# How to change the value of a control in a master page?

Tags: asp.net, .net

How to change the value of a control e.g. Literal in a user control and that User control is in master page and I want to change the value of that literal from content page.

```
((System.Web.UI.UserControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("ABC")).FindControl("XYZ").Text = "";
```

Here ABC is user control and XYZ is Literal control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to expose the values through public properties.

Put the following into your `ABC` control that contains the `XYZ` control:

```
public string XYZText
{
    get
    {
        return XYZControl.Text;
    }
    set
    {
       XYZControl.Text= value;
    }
}
```

Now you can expose this from the Master page by adding the following property to the MasterPage:

```
public string ExposeXYZText
{
    get
    {
        return ABCControl.XYZText;
    }
    set
    {
       ABCControl.XYZText = value;
    }
}
```

Then to use it from any content page, just do the following (where `MP` is the `MasterPage` class):

```
string text = ((MP)Page.Master).ExposeXYZText;
((MP)Page.Master).ExposeXYZText = "New Value";
```